# What is the safest way to stay current on 12.04 or 14.04, on dual boot with Windows 8?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade, windows-8

I am using 12.04 LTS, 64bit

For a while now, Update Manager has been telling me that New Hardware Support is available.  When that first happened, I of course tried to install it, but encountered errors and did not install.  I observed other users report the same problems here, but they were told they had selected to receive updates that weren't necessarily ready.  (I forget the exact words, but I checked, and I had not made such a selection either).

I also briefly attempted upgrading, which was recommended to others as a possible alternative, but I received errors (now long forgotten) which prevented me from even starting the process.  Due to this strange behavior, I have ignored the more recent "New Ubuntu Release" message in Update Manager.

Of additional concern, I read here that it is not uncommon for people with dual-boot (such as I have) to erase their entire hard drive, because the upgrade process (just as the original install of 12.04) is failing to detect the Windows 8 installation, or perhaps other data partitions.

So now I'm quite paranoid of upgrading.

What is the safest option for me to continue using 12.04, or 14.04, and receive all the important updates, without putting other data on my drive at risk?

Comment: Never heard that an upgrade erased an entire hard drive, where have you read that?
I'd try again to install updates, if you encounter errors, post a new question so we can resolve them.